Finding a closed form for the $n$-th term of the recurrence with $a_1=2$ and $a_{n}=\frac{2na_{n-1}+4n-4}{a_{n-1}+2n-2}$

Suppose
$$a_{n}=\frac{2na_{n-1}+4n-4}{a_{n-1}+2n-2}$$
with $a_1=2$. How can I figure out an expression for $a_n$ in terms of $n$?

This recurrence relation is from this question:
There is $n\times n$ squares made up of $n^2$ $1\times 1$ lattices.
And we will put an electrical resistor with a resistance of 1Ω in every $1\times 1$ lattices's every side. Then we will connect the two opposite vertices of this resistor with conductors. In this case, what is the size of the composite resistance?
And this recurrence relation's half of this answer is the value of the synthesized resistor above.

Can you try some simplifications? Your question will be closed if you do not provide context. Please ping me when you do so, so that I can retract my close vote

I'm sorry. I tried some simplifications. @DS

"I tried" isn't going to get you an answer? Did you review the link, which explains how we expect questions to be?

Oh...I'm not fluent in English , so I misunderstood. I apologize for the mistake.  I provide some motivation to this question. @DS

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231705/how-to-calculate-the-resistance-of-a-resistors-in-a-grid might help. Also, https://www.reddit.com/r/SolvedMathProblems/comments/2nh3fu/resistance_of_a_grid_of_resistors/ and maybe https://www.hajim.rochester.edu/ece/sites/friedman/papers/TCAS1_20_Mirror.pdf

Or maybe https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342340/how-do-you-determine-the-effective-resistance-of-a-finite-grid-of-resistors (I'm getting the impression it's a hard problem, but one that lots of people have looked at).

Thanks for the good information. @GerryMyerson

FWIW, the data strongly suggests that $a_n = 2\sqrt n + \frac12 - o(1)$.

Thank you so much for your help, but I was wondering if you could tell me how you did the check? @GregMartin

@GregMartin I managed to prove that based on the recurrence relation. Unfortunately the question is closed

@ioveri: The question has been reopened.

Some thoughts.
The recurrence relation is written as
$$a_n = 2n - \frac{4(n - 1)^2}{a_{n-1} + 2n - 2}.$$
According @Greg Martin's comment, we use the Mathematical Induction to prove that
$$2\sqrt{n} + \frac12 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \le a_n \le 2\sqrt{n} + \frac12, \quad n \ge 1. \tag{1}$$
When $n = 1$, (1) is true.
Assume that (1) is true for $n$ ($n\ge 1$).
For $n + 1$, by the inductive hypothesis, we have
\begin{align*}
 a_{n+1} &= 2(n + 1) - \frac{4n^2}{a_{n} + 2n}\\
 &\le 2(n + 1) - \frac{4n^2}{2\sqrt{n} + \frac12 + 2n}\\
 &\le 2\sqrt{n+1} + \frac12, \tag{2}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 a_{n+1} &= 2(n + 1) - \frac{4n^2}{a_{n} + 2n}\\
 &\ge 2(n + 1) - \frac{4n^2}{2\sqrt{n} + \frac12 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + 2n}\\
 &\ge 2\sqrt{n+1} + \frac12 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}.\tag{3}
\end{align*}
(The proof of (2) and (3) is given at the end.)
Thus, (1) is true for $n + 1$.
Thus, (1) is true.

Proof of (2).
Using $\sqrt{n+1} \ge \sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{2(n+1)}{2n+1}$ (easy), it suffices to prove that
$$2\sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{2(n+1)}{2n+1} + \frac12
\ge 2(n + 1) - \frac{4n^2}{2\sqrt{n} + \frac12 + 2n}$$
or
$$\frac{10n - 4\sqrt{n} - 3}{2(2n + 1)(2\sqrt{n} + 1)^2}\ge 0$$
which is true.
We are done.
Proof of (3).
Using $\sqrt{n+1} \ge \sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{2(n+1)}{2n+1}$ (easy), it suffices to prove that
$$2(n + 1) - \frac{4n^2}{2\sqrt{n} + \frac12 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + 2n}\ge 2\cdot \sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{2(n+1)}{2n+1} + \frac12 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{2(n+1)}{2n+1}}$$
or (letting $\sqrt{n} = m$)
$$\frac{22m^6 - 12m^5 + 33m^4 - 14m^3 + 15m^2 - 5m - 2}{2(2m - 1)(2m^2 + 3m + 2)(2m^2+1)m(m^2+1)}\ge 0$$
which is true.
We are done.
